# Can we listen to Rudra sukta if yajnopaveet is not done?

Tags: vedas, yagnopavitam, rudram

See, here i am not talking about chanting but listening. I belong to Kshatriya Varna by birth, but haven't done Yajnopaveet yet as no one in our family has done. So, can i just listen to rudra sukta of yajurveda?

Comment: It is commendable that you're asking for permission in an age where Gayatri mantra is blasted on loudspeakers for everyone to hear/chant. The reason behind restricting access of Vedas to Dwijas is similar to restricting access to nuclear codes to military personnel. If it's misused (as was the case by asuras), even the Deva granting boons faced trouble e.g. Shiva from Banasura. In Kali Yug, the problem is more severe, as people misinterpret Vedas because of their nastik nature. If your family has Bruhaspati or Purohit, ask them at least, instead of listening chantings on youtube.

Comment: Please do not accept answers which doesn't cite authentic sources.

Comment: @Rudra Looks like you're a new user, I would encourage you to take a [tour](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site. This will help you to understand how this site functions. If you need any help further, you may ping me in [main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) .

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no problem in listening. But remember, not to chant. Also, only listen after bathing and when your mind is pure.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism StackExchange! Answers posted here must be backed up by authentic sources. Kindly do so. Otherwise such answers will be deleted after 30 days of citation notice. Please visit help section to learn more.